# Sterilising seed starting trays with rubbing alcohol

Tags: seedlings, germination

Is wiping with rubbing alcohol enough to sterilise seed starting trays or is bleach or hydrogen peroxide necessary?

Comment: I don't think I've sterilized a seed tray in the last 40 years of gardening. The trick is to raise the plants in conditions that don't encourage pests and diseases to spread.

Comment: @Alephzero I have to plant some roselle. What steps do you recommend without sterilising? Do I keep the seed trays in full sun after planting? What about the cocopeat in which I put the seeds? Do I not sterilise that too?

Comment: What's the condition of the seed tray? New or used? If used, how much?

Comment: Used seed trays. Two to three times. If I buy new ones, do I have to sterilise them as well?